# JS instant output to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, validation, time, output

I want to get input from user, multiply it by 1.3 for example and output to window instantly, like as user types function is executing and displaying in it in HTML instantly. How do it do it?

Here my code

```js
 function calc() {

      amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
        num2 = 1.3;    
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = amount * num2; 
            return result;
}
```

```html
  <input id='amount', type="text" >
        <button onclick="calc()"> Buy Now! </button>
        <p> Result is: <br>
      <span id = "result">  </span>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="text"onkeyup="calc()">
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, you got some invalid HTML:

What's that comma?

```
<input id='amount', type="text" >
```

Attributes don't need any separator — just put a space:

```
<input id='amount' type="text" >
```

Getting rid of pointless spaces, a cleaner HTML fragment follows:

```
<input id='amount' type="text">
<button onclick="calc()">Buy Now!</button>
<p>Result is:<br>
<span id="result"></span>
```

Now, let's try to list some options:

- The `keydown` and `keypress` events won't work because they're fired before `value` changes.
- The `keyup` event, as suggested @Dmitri Usanov, will work only partially: it is called when the key releases (not as soon as the text is updated) and if you e.g. paste by right-clicking then it won't fire.
- The `input` is the solution. Note that it requires HTML5.

---

Working demo:

```js
function calc() {

  // Let's convert the input text to a number.
  const amount = +document.getElementById("amount").value;

  // The number to multiply by.
  const num2 = 1.3;

  // The number of decimal places we wish to truncate at.
  const precision = 2;

  const scale = 10 ** precision;

  return Math.round(amount * num2 * scale) / scale;
}

window.addEventListener("load", () => {

  const outputSpan = document.getElementById("result");

  document.getElementById("amount").addEventListener("input", () => {
    outputSpan.innerHTML = calc(this.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<input id='amount' type="text">
<button onclick="calc()">Buy Now!</button>
<p>Result is:<br>
<span id="result"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function calc(isEsc) {
  const num2 = 1.3;
  let result = document.getElementById("result"),
    amount = document.getElementById("amount");
  if (isEsc) {
    result.innerHTML = 0;
    amount.value = '';
  } else {
    result.innerHTML = amount.value * num2;
  }
}
document.onkeyup = function(evt) {
  evt = evt || window.event;
  var isEscape = false;
  if ("key" in evt) {
    isEscape = (evt.key == "Escape" || evt.key == "Esc");
  } else {
    isEscape = (evt.keyCode == 27);
  }
  calc(isEscape);
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="amount" />
<span id="result">0</span>
```